What is the unit for 'magnitude' in terms of the Isophotal diameter of a galaxy?
Every site and AI and Google say that one way of measuring a galaxy's diameter is in terms of its isophotal diameter, using the blue D25 standard, using units of, "25 mag per arcsec2".
But magnitude in astrophysics is a relative standard, so to speak, so...
How much brightness is '25 magnitudes'?

Magnitude is not relative

The D25 diameter is defined in terms of the diameter of a certain isophote: specifically, as you note, the isophote where the $B$-magnitude surface brightness has a value of 25 mag arcsec$^{-2}$.
The system traditionally used for this is the standard Johnson $B$-band, where the magnitude $m$ is defined as
$m = -2.5 \log_{10} (F_{\rm object} / F_{0})$
where $F_{\rm object}$ is the flux of the object and $F_{0}$ is the reference flux; in origin, this is the flux from the star Vega observed with the $B$ filter. I believe this is usually defined as $F_{0} = 4260$ Janskys (Jy).
So, working out the math, $m_{B} = 25$ corresponds to a flux of $4.26 \times 10^{-7}$ Jy.
